# How to Pass Data to Table%ROWTYPE in a oracle procedure from C# using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, plsql, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have a stored procedure that would insert data to a table after doing some logic, I am trying to pass the data from UI using C#, my data is in a format of data table.

```
PROCEDURE ins_upd_text (

p_title IN title_ref%ROWTYPE,

p_error OUT VARCHAR2,

p_returnvalue OUT NUMBER

);
```

we are using oracle managed dataaccess for database connectivity. how to send data from C# to oracle ROWTYPE parameter?